# Change the bootstrap-multiselect layout

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap-multiselect https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect with filtering option. Everything is working fine.
My drop down have around 80-90 values and due to which I have to provide the scroll. But issue is when I add scroll then search box also gets scrolled and it gets hidden when I go to the last value. I need to make sure that Search box will remain at the top and options will scroll under that.

So I have looked at the HTML code created by the bootstrap-multiselect and I found that the search control is also included in the the same parent.

```
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" aria-expanded="false">
 <li class="multiselect-item filter" value="0" role="menuitem">
   <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control multiselect-search" placeholder="Search">
      <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default multiselect-clear-filter"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></button></span>
 </div>
</li>
<li role="menuitem"><a tabindex="0"><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value=""> Please select</label></a></li>
<li class="multiselect-item multiselect-group" role="menuitem"><label>Test</label></li>
<li role="menuitem"><a tabindex="0"><label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="1"> Item 1</label></a></li>

</ul>
```

CSS Used:-

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Is there any CSS trick which I can use and make the search box fixed and options will scroll under it?
I already checked with template option provided by library but not got any success?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This  is my first answer on SO, if I've done anything wrong here, please let me know.

I was able to accomplish this recently by doing the following:

1. In CSS, set the position of the "frozen at top" items to "fixed", and make adjustments as necessary so that the remaining items are not visible behind them when the expanded part of the dropdown is scrolled.
2. In the multiselect's `onDropdownShown` event, call a function (see `resetDropdownHeight()` in the fiddle below) that will adjust the height of the expanded part of the dropdown based on the height of the frozen items.
3. In order to maintain correct dropdown height when filtering, modify the `buildFilter:` function in bootstrap-multiselect.js so as to call the `resetDropdownHeight()` function. If collapsible option groups are being utilized, do the same in the click event for `$('li.multiselect-group > a', this.$ul)`.

I was unclear on how to demonstrate item #3 (above) in the example fiddle, so here are the places to call `resetDropdownHeight()` in your modified version of bootstrap-multiselect.js:

buildFilter:
 1. Call it as the last line of the `clearBtn.on` event
 2. Call it as the last line of the large function for `this.searchTimeout`

"click" event for `$('li.multiselect-group > a', this.$ul)`:
 1. Call it as the last line of the event

See an example here (includes #1 and #2 only): https://jsfiddle.net/mjh42/v3bc9udk/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #freezeDemo + div.btn-group li.multiselect-filter {
                position: fixed;
                left: 1px; /* workaround for "position fixed" issue in Chrome desktop */
                top: 35px;
                width: 162px;
                z-index: 10;
                background-color: white;
            }

            #freezeDemo + div.btn-group li.multiselect-all {
                position: fixed;
                left: 1px; /* workaround for "position fixed" issue in Chrome desktop */
                top: 75px;
                width: 162px;
                z-index: 10;
                background-color: white;
                border-bottom: 1px solid;
            }

            #freezeDemo + div.btn-group ul.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu > li:not(.multiselect-filter):not(.multiselect-all) {
                position: relative;
                top: 65px;
            }

            #freezeDemo + div.btn-group ul.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu {
                top: 34px;
                width: 180px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="freezeDemo" multiple="multiple">
            <optgroup label="Group A">
                <option value="A1">Item A1</option>
                <option value="A2">Item A2</option>
                <option value="A3">Item A3</option>
                <option value="A4">Item A4</option>
                <option value="A5">Item A5</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group B">
                <option value="B1">Item B1</option>
                <option value="B2">Item B2</option>
                <option value="B3">Item B3</option>
                <option value="B4">Item B4</option>
                <option value="B5">Item B5</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $_dropdownMenu = null;

            initializeBootstrapMultiselect();

            function initializeBootstrapMultiselect() {
                $('#freezeDemo').multiselect({
                    buttonWidth: '180px',
                    enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    enableFiltering: true,
                    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
                    maxHeight: 200,
                    onDropdownShown: function(event) {
                        resetDropdownHeight();
                    }
                });

                $_dropdownMenu = $('#freezeDemo + div.btn-group > button.multiselect.dropdown-toggle.btn.btn-default ~ ul.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu');
            }

            function resetDropdownHeight() {
                if ($_dropdownMenu !== null) {
                    $_dropdownMenu.css('height', 'auto');

                    var filterHeight = $('li.multiselect-filter', $_dropdownMenu).height();
                    var selectAllHeight = $('li.multiselect-all', $_dropdownMenu).height();

                    if (isNaN(filterHeight)) { filterHeight = 0 }
                    if (isNaN(selectAllHeight)) { selectAllHeight = 0 }

                    var heightAdjustment = filterHeight + selectAllHeight;
                    var currentDropdownHeight = $_filterDropdownMenu.height();
                    var newHeight = (currentDropdownHeight + heightAdjustment).toString() + 'px';

                    $_dropdownMenu.css('height', newHeight);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add this template in jQuery 
   templates: {

   ```
            ul: '<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="height:250px;overflow-y:scroll;"></ul>'
       }
   ```